# Install a new module without FTP

Tags: 8, commerce

Am new to drupal, am working on version 8.3.5 trying to install a new module administration menu to my localhost without FTP.

I have extracted all files of module to /sites/all/modules folder.The menu is displaying in 'Extend' section but not displaying in my website.

The modules are 'checked' too, but how to enable it and display in my website? Thanks

I have executed this command sudo chown -R www-data sites/all/modules
too.

1. Current output:-(Only one admin toolbar already there after installation of drupal)

[image]

2. Current Settings in Extend section: (Admin toolbar always checked and unable to uncheck too.How to activate and deactivate this module here?)
3. Expected Output is two admin toolbar like this:- (Below screenshot is an example of administration menu module in drupal7)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont get double menu's as shown in screenshot. Admin Toolbar extends core toolbar to show as drop-down. Kindly refer [Admin Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar)  for more information

Comment: @A Ajay Reddy Thank you so much for the help, i have extracted the admin toolbar modules to website_folder/modules/contrib folder.How can i enable it now?Admin Tool bar is already checked in Extend section now.Thanks

Comment: If the module is enabled then the admin toolbar is at the top of the site. Beyond maybe the role not having permissions, theres not much more to go on here without more description. Are you sure all files are extracted? Are you sure it was for 8.x?

Comment: @kevin i have extracted the files to localhost/website/modules/contrib folder.All i can see only one admin toolbar which i already have, am expecting one more toolbar should appear at the top, sorry if am wrong.Also in the 'Extend' section admin toolbar is checked too.

Comment: @youv can u send a screenshot of what u have in website and what ur expecting.

Comment: @AAjayReddy I have attached the screenshots.Thanks

Comment: @youv : Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Download module and extract into modules folder (for drupal 8)

or you can run this command

sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/drupal folder name/
(For ubuntu)